# Integrating Cortana into Hololens app

Tags: hololens, cortana

I am trying to make a Hololens app where I can use voice command to pull up data. Is there an API for Cortana out there? Do I need to get a license from Microsoft? If there is none, is there a good API to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is pull up Cortana there is a simple line of code to do so, but I don't think it will be quite what you expect.

`UnityEngine.WSA.Launcher.LaunchUri("ms-cortana://Reactive/?StartMode=Reactive&ListeningMode=True", true);`

I used this to pull up Skype from within another Unity app. However, it is quite a hassle to do so. Most of the time when you ask Cortana a question, she will exit your app and open up her own app and bring up the information.

There is not really an API out there for her and she doesn't have all of the functionality on the HoloLens as she does on a normal desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `KeywordRecognizer` as follows:

```
List<string> keywords = new List<string>();
keywords.Add("Start game");
keywordRecognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(keywords.ToArray());
keywordRecognizer.OnPhraseRecognized += KeywordRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized;
keywordRecognizer.Start();
```

`...`

```
private void KeywordRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```